# How to ignore quotes between quotes with CSVReader(Java)?

Tags: java, csv

I'm reading from csv file and i'd like to ignore quotes between other quotes.
Example: 'blabla, "something with "quotes" and "more"",blabla..'

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(r,',','\0'); 
                String[] nextLine; 
                List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
                while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
                }
```

It works with string like 'aaa, bbb, "ccc ddd", eee'

Comment: What does _ignore quotes_ mean? What is the expected array supposed to look like? Did you try using `\"` as the quote char instead of `\0`. `new CSVReader(r,',','\"')`

Comment: i have some csv files with strings: str1== 'aaa,bbb,ccc'..... str2== 'aaa, "bbb, ccc", ddd'.... str3== 'aaa,"bbb "ccc" ddd "eee"",fff'. If i use `new CSVReader(r,',','\0')` it only works with str1 and str2. Otherwise if i use `new CSVReader(r,',','\"')` it only works with str1 and str3

Comment: "ignore quotes" -> i mean that i want to retrieve elements between commas as they are, indifferently if they have quotes inside or similar.

Comment: Define _works_, because `\"` seems to do a job well done for all three strings. Notice that `Arrays.toString(nextLine)` might be misleading in this case for `str2`, because `bbc, ccc` is in fact a single element. Use `System.out.println(nextLine.length)` to clarify the amount of elements in the array.